# PlaySound() slows down process

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code in my program:

```
self["text"]="✖"              
self["bg"]="red"              
self["relief"] = SUNKEN
self.banged = True
self.lost = True
self.lettersLeft = 0
self.lettersBanged = self.lettB
winsound.PlaySound('sound.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
messagebox.showerror("Letter Banging","Sorry, you lost the game!", parent=self)
for key in self.squares.keys():
    if self.squares[key].value == 3:
        self.squares[key].banged = False
        self.squares[key].expose()
```

I have just added the `winsound.PlaySound('sound.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)` part and it has slowed down my program. Infact, it plays the sound first and then does what is before it. I am using Python with tKinter. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try using multi process?

Comment: I am sorry for the wrong phrase. I mean multithread. You can try this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm
Hope this helps. In your case, try using another thread for playing the sound.

Comment: The definition can be easily found around the internet, or in the link given above. But the idea is
You seperate `winsound.PlaySound('sound.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)` into a different function, let's call `playsound()`. To create the thread and run it, you can use `thread.start_new_thread( playsound, () )` to call the playsound function. Remember to import the `thread` library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you alter the property of a widget, such as editing content, background and relief, this change does not appear immediately, they are recorded, and only take effect when you give hand to the mainloop which provoke redraw of your application. This lead to the behavior you observed: the sound is played, then the callback ends and the redraw showing your change happens.

All the time that you will spend in a callback playing the sound, your application will be not responsive. If you estimate your sound is short enough, you can add  `self.update()` somewhere between the UI change you want to show first and the call to PlaySound.

If you want to avoid any unresponsiveness in your app, you can play the sound in another thread

```
sound_thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda:winsound.PlaySound('sound.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME))
sound_thread.start()
```